# Disable input focus on click of label

Tags: html, angularjs

I have some pre-written code by a developer, Which I have to modify, In that code, A directive is created using textboxe is used inside label, And I added another custom directive in that directive. So the final rendered HTML looks like.

```
<label class="myClass">
  <div><input type="text" ng-model="someModel"></div>
  <my-custom-tag>
    <div class="customDropdown">
      dropdownBox
    </div>
  </my-custom-tag>
</label>
```

As this div.customDropdown is inside label, whenever I click on dropdown, that click is going to textbox also.

So My question is, **Is there any way to disable label feature of focusing input elements?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does it in vanilla JavaScript:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if(e.target.className === 'customDropdown') {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if(e.target.className === 'customDropdown') {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<label class="myClass">
  <div><input type="text" ng-model="someModel"></div>
  <my-custom-tag>
    <div class="customDropdown">
      dropdownBox
    </div>
  </my-custom-tag>
</label>
```

Comment: preventDefault worked for me. Now the problem with click event handlers for child elements of `.customDropdown`

Comment: For child elements, you could do `if(e.target.className === 'customDropdown' || e.target.parentNode.className === 'customDropdown') {...`.  For grandchildren, great-grandchildren, etc., you could add more `parentNode` tests.  But at that point, you may be better off traversing up the DOM.  Perhaps there's an Angular way of testing if an element has an ancestor with a given tag?

Answer (score 3):

You can prevent the default action of the label's click event using jQuery.

```
$('label.myClass').click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
});​
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to use  div or span at the place of the label and if you want you can write it before or inside that ..

I know its not simple but you can do it ..

Comment: I already mentioned, the code is written by another developer, so I cant do more modification in that. :(

Comment: actually it is very simple if you can't please create jsfiddle i love to help you .